# OpenCV_HelloWorld project in VC++ 2010 Runtime Error:

Tags: visual-studio-2010, runtime

I set up the environment according to this tutorial:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010

However the picture they want you to use is no longer there, so I just saved the supplied screen shot with the same name as the original file.

Builds fine, Begins to run but then I get a runtime error

Here is the runtime error:
OpenCV_HelloWorld.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.

I looked in Event Viewer and found that it also set off a another error but did not announce

Here is the unannounced error:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\OpenCV2.1\bin\cxcore210d.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

As you can see it says to use sxstrace.exe however I don't appear to have that program. After a quick Google I read that the program was included in the Microsoft Windows Platform SDK, so I'm downloading the most relevant version (windows 7 version for c# and .net) and installing that to follow up on that, I'll post what I find as it comes.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Oops, wrong stack page D:. My apologies.

Comment: Having the same error...not sure how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpectedly the project builds and runs now. The only modifications made were removing spaces in the c++ directory and linker options from the tutorial. External changes were the completed installation of the windows platform SDK, however OpenCV has no dependencies with windows platform sdk. I am unsure how it was resolved, but it's no longer a problem.